# How to draw audio spectrum with vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I need draw audio spectrum on canvas from user's media file with vanilla javascript. but, I cannot solve that problem. because, everybody use savesurfer.js.

I did use createAnalyser on Web audio API. but, 'CreateAnalyser' is cannot get frequency of user's media file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="file">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
    <script>

        // draw an oscilloscope of the current audio source
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var canvasCtx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var WIDTH = canvas.width;
        var HEIGHT = canvas.height;
        var audio = null;

        document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
            var file = e.target.files[0];
            var fileName = file.name;
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            var audio = new Audio(fileName);
            var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();

            fileReader.onload = function(e) {
                var buffer = e.target.result;
                var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
                audioCtx.decodeAudioData(buffer, (buffer) => {
                    source.loop = true;

                    var offlineAudioCtx = new OfflineAudioContext(buffer);

                    offlineAudioCtx.startRendering().then(function(buffer) {
                        source.buffer = buffer;
                        source.connect(analyser);
                        source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
                        var dataArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
                        analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);
                        console.log(dataArray);
                    });
                });
            }
            fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a few things here. First, you have nothing connected to the input of the analyser node, so you need to do something like

```
source.connect(analyser);
```

You should now get non-constant output.

You probably don't want to create a new AudioContext (and AnalyserNode) on each event.  You only need one of each.

You probably also want to call `analyser.getByteTimeDomainData()` more than once per event, but maybe that's ok.  Also, the actual length of the time dome data is `fftSize`, not `frequencyBinCount`.  What you've done here is only copy half of the time-domain data that's available.  Maybe that's ok for what you want too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but, I could not solve still this issue. I updated my source code on this question. can you check the source code one more time?

Comment: dataArray variable is still dont have frequency of user's media file.

Comment: I don't understand why you added an offline audio context.  And your use of it is wrong.  You need to set up the graph and then call `startRendering`.  And the construction of the offline context is probably incorrect.  It works because `buffer` has the right attributes, but this probably isn't doing what you think it is.  Perhaps you should read https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-offlineaudiocontext-startrendering in more detail.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry. I Unfamilier use web audio api. so, OfflineAudioContext is not have special mean bacause My code is just followwd many examples.

Comment: You might want to try some WebAudio tutorials then.  But also, if you posted a complete (but small!) example (via jsfiddle or codepen or something), then perhaps I could give some better advice on what to do.  Can't promise it though.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your advice!